# A holonomic function and its singularity

Tags: co.combinatorics, differential-equations, enumerative-combinatorics, symmetric-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

The following series where $q_i , h$ are constant parameters. $G(z)$ is a rational function.
$$F(x):=\sum_{d= 1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^d (-1)^{d-k} \, s_{(k, 1^{d-k})}(\tfrac{q_1}{h}, \tfrac{q_2}{h}, \ldots, \tfrac{q_r}{h}) \, \prod_{i=1}^d G((k-i)h) \, x^{d} \label{1}\tag{$*$}
 $$
It can be shown that $F(x)$ is holonomic, which means it satisfies a linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients.
If $F(x)$ is holonomic over $\mathbb{C}(h)$, then there exist polynomials $P_0, P_1, \ldots, P_r$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}(h,q_i)$ such that
$$
\left[ P_r(x) \, \frac{\partial^r}{\partial x^r} + P_{r-1}(x) \, \frac{\partial^{r-1}}{\partial x^{r-1}} + \cdots + P_1(x) \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + P_0(x) \right] F(x) = 0.
$$

So what I understand the pole structure of $F(x)$ is a subset of zeros of $P_r (x)$?
My first question in this particular case can I find polynomial $P_r (x)$, I have the existence.
Let me explain how we conclude $F(x)$ being holomorphic. Basically, we use the closure properties of the holonomic function.
$$
s_{k,1^{d-k}}({\bf{q}})=\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^{j+1}h_{k-j}({\bf{q}}) \, e_{d-k+j}({\bf{q}}),
$$
where $h_{n}$ and $e_{n}$ are the complete homogeneous and elementary symmetric functions, respectively.
Now we can write $(*)$ as
$$ \sum_{d= 1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^d \prod_{i=1}^{k} G(ih) \prod_{i=1}^{d-k} G(-ih) \sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1} (-1)^{d-\ell+1}h_{\ell}(\tfrac{q_1}{h}, \tfrac{q_2}{h}, \ldots, \tfrac{q_r}{h}) \, e_{(d-\ell)}(\tfrac{q_1}{h}, \tfrac{q_2}{h}, \ldots, \tfrac{q_r}{h}) \, x^{d}$$
Let
$$ 
a_{n}:=\prod_{i=1}^{n} G(ih),~ b_{n}:=\prod_{i=1}^{n} G(-ih),~c_{n}:=h_{n}(\tfrac{q_1}{h}, \tfrac{q_2}{h}, \ldots,\tfrac{q_{r}}{h}),~d_{n}:=(-1)^{n+1}e_{n}(\tfrac{q_1}{h}, \tfrac{q_2}{h}, \ldots,\tfrac{q_{r}}{h}).
$$

Now notice each of the series
$ \sum_i a_i x^i$ is holomorphic hence we conclude \eqref{1} being holomorphic.